# Split multiple flex children left and right

Tags: css, flexbox

I know when using `display: flex` you can use `margin-left: auto` on a child and that pushes it all the way to the right but if you do that with multiple children you end up with evenly distributed margins instead of them all sitting to the far left.

**Assuming HTML is uneditable**

I know you could create a class like so: http://jsfiddle.net/L943ckr5/

```css
.flex {
    display: flex;
}

.child {
    height: 30px;
    width: 50px;
    
    background-color: red;
}

.child:nth-child(even) {
    background-color: blue;
}

.end {
    margin-left: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex">
    <div class="child"></div>
    <div class="child"></div>
    <div class="child"></div>
    <div class="child end"></div>
    <div class="child"></div>
    <div class="child"></div>
</div>
```

But is there a way to individually target the last 3 children and 'float' them right but with Flex obviously. Something along the lines of `justify-self: flex-end;`

Comment: you could create two separate flex-boxes an put them side by side http://jsfiddle.net/maio/L943ckr5/2/

Comment: What about grouping child `divs` into parent `div`, and then "justifying" them with `flex`? Otherwise seems to be tough with flex itself, if you can't modify `html`, and you'll most likely need to resort to javascript.

Comment: I should have probably noted assuming HTML is uneditable otherwise i would go the double flex column route!

Comment: Are you searching for `.child:nth-last-of-type(3)` or is this a general question?

Comment: General question. I'm aware i could use that instead of `.end` but i'm after something that acts like `float: right` but with flex children

Answer (score 0):

In case of you're being OK with using `jQuery` to tackle this problem, I got solution to wrap every group of 3 child `divs` into a parent `div`, and spread them as a column.
This might get helpful if you don't know the exact number of `child` `divs` in your `markup`.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/L943ckr5/6/)

**HTML:**

```
<div class="flex">
    <div class="child"></div>
    <div class="child"></div>
    <div class="child"></div>
    <div class="child"></div>
    <div class="child"></div>
    <div class="child"></div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.flex {
    display: flex;
    justify-content:space-between;
}
.flex-container {
    display:flex;
}
.child {
    height: 30px;
    width: 50px;
    background-color: red;
}
.child:nth-child(even) {
    background-color: blue;
}
```

**jQuery:**

```
var arr = $(".child"),
    templ = '<div class="flex-container"></div>';

for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i+=3) {
  arr.slice(i, i+3).wrapAll(templ);
}
```

Comment: I wouldn't like to use JS tbh as i could just use `:nth-child()` and then `margin-left: auto` that child and it does the split. Just wondered if there was a more verbose way in CSS to do it

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean like this:

```
.child:nth-last-child(3) {
margin-left: auto;
}
```

```css
.flex {
    display: flex;
}

.child {
    height: 30px;
    width: 50px;    
    background-color: red;
}

.child:nth-child(even) {
    background-color: blue;
}

.child:nth-last-child(3) {
margin-left: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex">
    <div class="child"></div>
    <div class="child"></div>
    <div class="child"></div>
    <div class="child"></div>
    <div class="child"></div>
    <div class="child"></div>
</div>
```

As far as I know there is no property to add to ***each*** of the elements that would achieve the same effect.

Comment: Yea like that basically i was just curious if there was a way to do it to each of the elements but it appears not!